# Trying to generate a different password everytime user nearly finds the password

Tags: c++, passwords

First of all English is not my first language so please tell me if you didn't understand something.

The Assignment is,There is a 9 digit, only integer Password, for example : 385987231.The user will enter a 9 digit input.Everytime user gets close to guessing/finding the password,the password will be changed.If 8 digits of the password and users input matches,password will be changed.The order of the digits are not important.Only thing matters is that if eight of the digits matches,password changes.

For example : The Password is 123456789, users input 223456789 in this case password changes itself.

There is an hiddenPassword it is created at the beginning and there is a Password it is the input from user.

I have made passwordChecker and passwordCreater functions.passwordChecker checks 2 numbers in an array if they match or not and everytime they match counter goes 1 up.If counter is 8 then hiddenPassword changes. if not it doesn't change.

passwordCreater function creates random password.Because it is in char variable i add 48 to make it integer in refer to ASCII Table and the problem begins.

Even though function creates a password,it does not return the password and the password is not correct.
And i do not think passwordChecker works because it is a void function so that it does not return anything.When i call passwordCreater in passwordChecker nothing comes and nothing goes.Sadly.

```
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <ctime> 
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;


char passwordCreater()
{
    srand((unsigned)time(0)); 
    char random_integer[20]; 
    for (int index=0; index<9; index++)
    {
        random_integer[index] = (rand()%10)+1; 
        random_integer[index]=random_integer[index]+48;
        cout << random_integer << endl; 
    } 
    return random_integer[9];
}



void passwordChecker (char a[9], char b[9])
{
    int counter;
    for (int i=0;i++;i<10)
    {
        if (a[i]==b[i])
        {
            counter=counter+1;
        } 
        else
        {
            counter=counter;
        }
    }
    printf("%d \n",counter);
    if (counter==8)
    {
        b[9]==passwordCreater();
    } 
    else if (counter==9)
    {
        printf("Password is right!");
    } 
    else
    {
        printf("Password is wrong!");
        return;
    }
}


int main()
{
    char hiddenPassword[9];
    hiddenPassword[9]==passwordCreater();
    char password[9];
    printf("%s \n",hiddenPassword);
    printf("------------------------");
    printf("\n       PASSWORD:       ");
    printf("\n------------------------\n");
    scanf("%s", &password);
    printf("%s \n",password);
    passwordChecker(password,hiddenPassword);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: **WARNING**: Using [`rand()` is highly problematic](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) and you’re strongly encouraged to use an appropriate [random number generator facility in the Standard Library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) that produces high-quality random values. Your use of `time(NULL)` as a random number seed means that this will produce identical results if run in the same second, and on many platforms `rand()` is [*barely* random at all](http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25).

Comment: In C++ you should be using `std::cout << password` instead of `printf`, plus also `std::cin >> password` instead of `scanf`. You should also use `std::string` instead of C-style character buffers. **`char[9]` holds 8 characters**.

Comment: `hiddenPassword[9]==passwordCreater();` -- Do you see something strange in this line of code?

Comment: can `0` be a part of the `hiddenPassword`? e.g. `102542249` for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution: Generates random seed *separately and just once*.

Generates random password rather simply, then checks for user input through analyzing it in *2 parts*.

**#1:** Checks if they are the same lengths before

**#2:** comparing each individual digit in the input password, and gives feedback accordingly. If the `Counter` reads 8, it creates a new password. Enjoy.

**EDIT:** I've used `<random>` header instead of `srand(time(0))` and `rand()` to get rid of the bias.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

mt19937 Generator;
uniform_int_distribution<int> Distribution(0,9);

void GenerateRandomSeed() {
    Generator.seed(time(0));
}

vector<char> CreatePassword() {
    cout << "Hidden password: ";
    vector<char> Password;
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
        Password.push_back(Distribution(Generator) + 48);
        cout << Password[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
    return Password;
}

bool isPasswordCorrect(string & InputPassword, vector<char> & HiddenPassword) {
    if(InputPassword.length() != HiddenPassword.size()) {
        cout << "Password is wrong!" << endl;
        return false;
    }
    int Counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < InputPassword.length(); ++i) {
        if(InputPassword[i] == HiddenPassword[i])
            ++Counter;
    }
    if(Counter == 8) {
        HiddenPassword = CreatePassword();
        cout << "Password was close, new hidden password has been generated" << endl;
        return false;
    } else if (Counter == 9){
        cout << "Password is right!" << endl;
        return true;
    }
    cout << "Password is wrong!" << endl;
    return false;
}

int main() {
    GenerateRandomSeed();
    string InputPassword;
    vector<char> HiddenPassword;
    HiddenPassword = CreatePassword();
    do {
        cout << "Input correct password please: ";
        cin >> InputPassword;
    } while (!isPasswordCorrect(InputPassword, HiddenPassword));
    return 0;
}
```